# Twitch bot message formatting issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I decided i wanted to make a twitch bot in Python I checked online and found a little guide on how to do it replicated the code so I can see how one works before rewriting it. But the issue i'm running into is when the bot detects one of the words i get the below error. I can't quite figure out what it means by bytes-like object and how i could format the message to be as such.

It's most likely a very small thing I missed or something i don't know because i'm not too experienced in any sort of network programming currently. If anyone has any guidance that would be greatly appreciated.

Error:
File "C:/Users/Daniel/PycharmProjects/twitchBOT/bot.py", line 45, in 
detected
    s.send("PRIVMSG #buffet_time :this is a test")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1

```
# boy.py
import cfg
import socket
import re
import time


def chat(sock, msg):
    sock.send("PRIVMSG {} :{}".format(cfg.CHAN, msg))


def ban(sock, user):
    chat(sock, ".ban {}".format(user))


def timeout(sock, user, secs=1):
    chat(sock, ".timeout {}".format(user, secs))

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((cfg.HOST, cfg.PORT))
s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(cfg.PASS).encode("utf-8"))
s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(cfg.NICK).encode("utf-8"))
s.send("JOIN {}\r\n".format(cfg.CHAN).encode("utf-8"))
CHAT_MSG = re.compile(r"^:\w+!\w+@\w+\.tmi\.twitch\.tv PRIVMSG #\w+ :")

while True:

    response = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    if response == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
        s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
        print("Pong!")

    else:
        username = re.search(r"\w+", response).group(0)
        message = CHAT_MSG.sub("", response)
        print(username + ": " + message)

        for pattern in cfg.PATT:
            if re.match(pattern, message):
                print("detected")
                s.send(b"PRIVMSG #buffet_time :this is a test")
                print("sent")
                break

        time.sleep(1 / cfg.RATE)



#cfg.py 

HOST = "irc.twitch.tv"                          # irc server
PORT = 6667                                     # irc port#
NICK = "buffet_bot"                             # twitch name (lower case)
PASS = "oauth:[not showing here of course. ]"   # OAuth Token
CHAN = "#buffet_time"                           # channel to connect to

RATE = (20/30)                                  # delay

PATT = [
        r"badword1",
        r"badword2"
]
```

Comment: `send(b"text")` or `send("text".encode("utf8"))` will fix it.

Comment: didn't the fact that all `s.send()` commands apart from the ones you wrote have the string followed by `.encode("utf-8")` seem curious enough?

Comment: The issue is even when i had encoded it utf8 it doesnt actually send anything to the chat, it doesn't return an error but nothing appears in chat. That's my issue.

Comment: Again, what ForceBru said didn't fix it, it made it so it doesn't push an error but there is no message being sent to the chat which is what is intended, i had already dont the utf encoding before.

Comment: Well, look at what the server is doing. If your client is sending a message and the chat (the server) isn't displaying anything, then it seems the problem is something to do with how the server reads your message. Maybe you're not sending a valid message to the server and it's just dropping it on the ground? If it's looking for ASCII and you're sending unicode, that might be a problem as well...in other words, the server requires ASCII, but `socket.send(...)` requires unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specific error but running this in the latest build of Python 2.7 seems to fix the issue. I don't know why but

```
s.send("PRIVMSG #buffet_time :THIS IS SENT\n".encode("utf-8"))
```

works perfectly in 2.7 but not at all in 3.5.

If anyone ever figures out why this is the case i'd love to know!